# Flutter Container height not inheriting from ListView child

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I am building a page.dart where I need to build a dynamic ListView inside a child container and the ListView height is dynamic, so i can't define a fixed height for Container.

My page there some another thing's on top, then its structure actually is:

```
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
  Container(),//Container
  Container(
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
        Row(),
        Divider(),
        Row(),
        Divider(),
        Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
               //shrinkWrap: true, //tryied and not worked
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
               itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  buildItem(index, items.item[index]),
               itemCount: items.length,
               reverse: false,
               controller: listScrollController,
           )//ListView
        )
     ]
   )//Column
  )//Container
 ]
)//Stack
```

As I am not definig a Container height, the listview content is not appearing. If I define some height for Container it appears, but not inheriting the listview content, sometimes letting some itens out of height.

Have you any workaround for this?

Comment: Did you tried using mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min in Column ?

Comment: Tryied now and did not work.

Comment: did you tried both shrinkWrap and mainAxisSize ??

Comment: Yes, no success :/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this inside scaffold !

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(), //Container
      Container(
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        Row(),
        Divider(),
        Row(),
        Divider(),
        Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true, //tryied and not worked
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
            '$index',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          itemCount: list.length,
        ) //ListView
            )
      ]) //Column
          ) //Container
    ])
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can see the above example ! It worked for me as your code ! If it is still not working, its your code problem which you not posted here.